# Get and use server IP address on Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos, fedora

I have this Bash file that perfectly runs fine on each system I deploy but it needs to have server IP put in the command so it would work and I do enter it manually on each server but I was thinking is there a way to automate this process? For example let's say I need to have this command:

```
mycli serve --host x.x.x.x &
```

instead of replacing x.x.x.x on each server I want to have a Bash file that automatically retrieves server IP and runs that command with that IP?

Comment: Does your program not support using `0.0.0.0` to bind to all interfaces?

Comment: Do the servers have a single IP or are there multiple network devices?

Comment: The question is unclear for me: By "server IP" do you mean the IP of the server you are running this script or is it an external server your script connects to (always the same IP)? If unsure just explain how you currently get the value for x.x.x.x.

Answer (score 3):

set a variable at the beginning of the script that sets the IP address, and then use that variable in the actual command the script is running.

off the top of my head, something like

`IPADDR=$(ip addr show |grep 'inet '|grep -v 127.0.0.1 |awk '{print $2}'| cut -d/ -f1)`

then in the script, just use `$IPADDR` where you would put the IP.

This will only work correctly on a server with a single IP and a single loopback of 127.0.0.1, and there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Slightly cleaner than `grep`ping into `awk` into `cut` to get the first IPv4 address outside of loopback:  `ip addr show | sed -n '/2:/,//{/inet/{s_/.*__;s/^.* //;p;q;};}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "host" has a single IP address, you can do something like:

```
MYHOSTIP=$(host `hostname` | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $NF; }') mycli servie --host $MYHOSTIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your system has 2 ethernet devices, `eth0` and `eth1` and `eth0` is connected to your LAN, say IPs 192.168.1.X and your `eth1` device is connected to your ISP (WAN) you're going to want to use the following `ifconfig` command to get your IP for the WAN side.

**NOTE:** The 1st 2 ways assume that you're running them against a computer that has 2 ethernet devices and that one of them is connected to your ISP (cable modem and/or DSL modem). In this scenario the ethernet device (eth1) will be configured with your IP address on the internet (WAN IP).

**1st way**

```
                          +------------------------+
  +--------+    WAN IP    |   Computer that wants  |  LAN IP
  |Internet|--------------|     to know WAN IP     |------------
  +--------+  54.234.1.33 | +------+      +------+ | 192.168.1.1
                          +-| eth1 |------| eth0 |-+
                            +------+      +------+

% ifconfig eth1 | awk '/inet / { print $2 }' | sed -e s/addr://
54.234.1.33
```

You can also use the `ip` command.

```
% ip -4 addr show eth1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | sed 's#/.*##'
54.234.1.33
```

**2nd way**

If you need to find this out from a system that sits only on the LAN you could setup a passphrase-less ssh key and add it to an account on your LAN machine so that it could remotely access the system with the WAN access like so.

```
                                                            +----------------+
  +--------+    WAN IP      +-------------+      LAN IP     | Computer that  |
  |Internet|----------------|remote-server|-----------------| wants to know  |
  +--------+  54.234.1.33  +----+-----+----+  192.168.1.x  +----+ WAN IP     |
                           |eth1|     |eth0|               |eth0|------------+
                           +----+     +----+               +----+

% ssh ruser1@remote-server "ifconfig eth1 | awk '/inet / { print \$2 }' | sed -e s/addr://"
54.234.1.33
```

**3rd way**

If you're unable to ssh into the box that has WAN access and you're using a home router/switch such as a Linksys or Netgear box. You may be able to get the IP from that device via a HTTP status page. I've done this in the past as well, something similar to what's described in this [whatismyip.com forum post](http://forum.whatismyip.com/f36/script-to-watch-and-log-dynamic-ip-changes-t609/).

```
                                                               192.168.1.2
                                                            +----------------+
  +--------+    WAN IP      +-------------+      LAN IP     | Computer that  |
  |Internet|----------------|router/switch|-----------------| wants to know  |
  +--------+  54.234.1.33   +-------------+   192.168.1.x  +----+ WAN IP     |
                              192.168.1.1                  |eth0|------------+
                                                           +----+

# something like this....

% wget -q -O - http://<username>:<password>@192.168.1.1/Status_Router.asp | grep "ipaddress" | cut -d" " -f2
```

**NOTE:** This approach is highly dependent on which router/switch you have, whether it's a Linksys, Netgear, etc. brand. Each will have their own unique page with the WAN IP on it.

**4th way**

Sending a query against an external internet site which will report back your WAN IP address.

**NOTE:** I'm aware that the original question mentioned that they were looking for alternatives to this approach but I'm putting it in here so that this answer covers all the bases.

```
                                                        +---------------+
  +-------------+   +--------+   +------+     LAN IP    | Computer that |
  |whatsmyip.com|---|Internet|---|router|---------------| wants to know |
  +-------------+   +--------+   +------+  192.168.1.x +----+ WAN IP    |
you're 54.234.1.33                                     |eth0|-----------+
                                                       +----+

# 1st server
% wget -qO - ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com
54.234.1.33

# 2nd server
% curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'

{"ip":"54.234.1.33"}
% curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=txt'
54.234.1.33

# 3rd server
% curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed 's#.*Address: \(.*\)</b.*#\1#'
54.234.1.33
```

Additional info is available here: [HOWTO: Check you external IP Address from the command line](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=526176).

#### References

- [How can I get my public IP address from the command line, if I am behind a router?](https://superuser.com/questions/522887/how-can-i-get-my-public-ip-address-from-the-command-line-if-i-am-behind-a-route)